# Can I get the queryhash value for a given query without SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

When looking at SQL Server DMVs or a query plan, the query hash for a given query is given as a hex value (e.g. something like `0x348D44A83C9300EC`).

I can retrieve the query hash value for a query using SQL Server and estimating a plan.

Can I do it without SQL Server? Or is this string --> queryhash function just not available that way?

I looked in a library like https://github.com/microsoft/SqlScriptDOM, but the parser doesn't seem to provide anything like that.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what exactly you need the hash for. How are you planning to use it?

Comment: I've only seen it for the [sql handle](https://www.sql.kiwi/2020/10/sqlhandle-and-sql-server-batch-text-hash.html), but perhaps there's some similarity.

Comment: @mustaccio We have a warehouse of query statistics pulled from several servers regularly. Think of query store, but for many servers. Those queries are indexed by queryhash. I could use such a function to help me answer "is this query used anywhere".

Comment: Thanks @ErikDarling. That looks pretty interesting actually

Comment: Still unclear. "is this query used anywhere" - as in, find that query in the source code of a program? Or as in, is it the same query currently running on some instance of SQL Server?

Comment: It's unclear because it's irrelevant to the question. We want to know if a query is being executed on any server. 
I'm not going to follow up on our use case any more.

Comment: It looks like a good additional question to ask would be: is the query hash guaranteed to be the same for the same query text, if the query is executed on different servers and/or at different times.

Comment: Yes, it is the same, (queryplanhash is a different story)

Comment: Related https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183046/3690

Comment: Ooh, thanks @MartinSmith, 
I'd be okay closing this question as a duplicate of that other one. I didn't see that other one when writing this question.

Comment: I don't think you are going to have much luck with this as `SELECT * FROM master..spt_values v1 WHERE type = 'A' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 10;` returns the same hash as 
`SELECT * FROM master..spt_values v2 WHERE type = 'B' AND number >= 1 AND number <= 10;` - so the hash is clearly after some normalization process and not sensitive to table aliases and some different ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: It turns out in practice that we do have luck with this. 
In practice those collisions are rare, (and actually interesting). 
In other words, that normalization is a feature, not a bug (the way we're using it). Grouping by bigger buckets helps us.